# Get previous page label text

Tags: jquery, label, hidden-field

I am trying to get the previous .aspx page label / hidden field  text on my current page(htm). But I am getting the error 'cannot read property document of null'.

I am using jquery 1.7.1

Below is my code.

CURRENT PAGE:

```
document.getElementById('inputList').value = window.opener.document.getElementById('lbladd').value;
```

Previous page I fetch the vaue from the database and set it to the label or hidden field.

CODE:

```
                string s = DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getAddress", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@education_details_id", s);
                SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adap.Fill(ds);
                if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string _stradd = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["InputAddress"]);
                    hdnAddress.Value=_stradd;
                    lbladd.Text = _stradd;

                    Response.Redirect("xyz.htm");

                }
```